# Help converting SQL nested sub-query to join query for mysql 4.0 compatibility

Tags: sql, mysql, left-join, self-join, subquery

I have a nested SQL query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT(topic_id)
FROM bb_posts 
WHERE topic_id NOT IN ( 
  SELECT topic_id FROM bb_posts 
  WHERE poster_id = $user_id AND post_status = 0 ) 
ORDER BY post_time DESC
```

My webserver runs MySQL 4.0 which doesnt allow nested queries. Can some SQL guru suggest the same query using the JOIN lingo? i tried and tried and tried... but i can't figure this out. Feeling dumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that topic_id is not nullable, you can do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(T1.topic_id)
FROM bb_posts As T1
    Left Join bb_posts As T2
        On T2.topic_id = T1.topic_id
            And T2.poster_id = $user_id
            And T2.post_status = 0
Where T2.topic_id Is Null
ORDER BY T1.post_time DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what your requirement is but by looking at your query I think this should suffice.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(topic_id) 
FROM bb_posts 
WHERE poster_id <> $user_id OR post_status <> 0 
ORDER BY post_time DESC
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `posterid <> $user_id Or post_status <> 0`?

Comment: The requirements basically are: i want to have a list of topics the user hasn't replied to or started himself. Each topic has at least one or more posts with a topic_id and a user_id. Your answer will return also posts the user has replied to.

Comment: Yes Thomas, you are right. Edited my answer. I guess trying to be quick on the gun forced an error. :P